# Does Azure Offline Sync for Mobile Apps optimize for areas with Poor Network

Tags: cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services

How does this Azure Offline Sync feature behave in areas with very slow network speed. Presently we are chunking our payloads and send them to the server in bits. I would like to know if moving to azure offline sync will do the same or better

Answer (score -1):

Offline data sync is a client and server SDK feature of Azure Mobile Apps that makes it easy for developers to create apps that are functional without a network connection.
When your app is in offline mode, you can still create and modify data, which are saved to a local store. When the app is back online, it can synchronize local changes with your Azure Mobile App backend. The feature also includes support for detecting conflicts when the same record is changed on both the client and the backend. Conflicts can then be handled either on the server or the client.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync.

Also, you can refer this article to enable offline sync for your Cordova mobile app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-offline-data.